# Not able to connect to docker port from host machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm not able to access docker port 8080 from the host machine. We have a docker container with a `React` application. We are able to get the landing page from inside the container but not from the host.

From the container:

```
root@d4947f7b1710:/# wget localhost:8080
--2019-04-01 19:38:00--  http://localhost:8080/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 492 [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html                                    100%[===============================================================================================>]     492  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2019-04-01 19:38:00 (49.5 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [492/492]
```

From the host:

```
wget localhost:8000
--2019-04-01 19:38:59--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.Retrying.
```

Also tried `wget 0.0.0.0:8000` but got the same result.
The ports seem to be mapped correctly:

```
docker port d4947f7b1710
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Command used to start the container:

docker run -d -p 8000:8080 `<docker repo>`:`<version>`

Comment: well it does say ...connected so i asume its some other problem

Comment: did you get another docker container running before or is this your first time ?

Comment: I have bit of experience with dockers. Not a complete new bee.

Comment: ok then its unlikely that your docker host runs on a differnet ip or needs additional port mappings oO ...

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you inverted the ports from what I see in the last part of your post

Comment: *facepalm* I thought so too for a moment but just thought it was a differnet way of printing it -.-

Comment: Here is the command used to start the container:
docker run -d -p 8000:8080 <docker repo>:<version>

Comment: I though that too, tried both ports (8000,8080) but does not work.

Comment: It does show flipped than what you see in regular `docker ps` command, here are the results for both commands:



docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
1eff46acc65f        <Container>   "/bin/sh -c 'npm sta…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp, 5000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8080/tcp   modest_meninsky


docker port 1eff46acc65f
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000